# siunitx uses wrong font for \degreeCelsius in math-sf

Tags: math-mode, siunitx

Even though I am using the siunitx-Parameters `detect-all` and `math-sf=\mathrm` to have units typeset with the serif math font when inside a math context, the `\degreeCelsius` remains typeset in `\mathsf`.

Is this done so intentionally?
How could I achieve my desired output?

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all, math-sf = \mathrm}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{ l l | l }
        I get ...              &                          & I want ...                  \\
        in text mode:          & in math mode:            & in math mode:               \\
        \SI{5}{m}              & $\SI{5}{m}$              & $5\,\mathrm{m}$             \\
        \SI{5}{\degreeCelsius} & $\SI{5}{\degreeCelsius}$ & $5\,\si{\degree}\mathrm{C}$
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above Latex document code]

Comment: Please tell us which version of `siunitx` you employ. FWIW, I can *not* replicate the issue you encounter with an up-to-date MacTeX2020 distribution, which currently employs version `2020/02/25 v2.8b` of the `siunitx` package.

Comment: As Mico, I cannot replicate your problem on Win10 MikTeX with `siunitx 2.8b`

Comment: Good point, the version is `2018/05/17 v2.7s`.
Glad to hear it's fixed now. Updating to TexLive 2020 is on my list anyway.

Comment: @Mico I don't think that this is due to siunitx changes, but to the change in textcomp symbol handling in the new latex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Thanks. The OP has replied in the meantime that he/she has been using a medieval-era version of `siunitx` and, presumably, the LaTeX format. Upgrading/updating to the latest version of TeXLive or MiktTeX should take care of the OP's issues...